# Removing element from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

Hi I have this array list of hashmaps

```
[{EndTime=09:00 AM, UserId=48, StartTime=08:00 AM, AppointmentId=79, Date=11/18/13},
{EndTime=09:00 AM, UserId=48, StartTime=08:00 AM, AppointmentId=80, Date=11/18/13},
{EndTime=09:00 AM, UserId=48, StartTime=08:00 AM, AppointmentId=81, Date=11/18/13},
{EndTime=09:00 AM, UserId=48, StartTime=08:00 AM, AppointmentId=82, Date=11/18/13},
{EndTime=09:00 AM, UserId=48, StartTime=08:00 AM, AppointmentId=83, Date=11/18/13},
{EndTime=09:00 AM, UserId=48, StartTime=08:00 AM, AppointmentId=85, Date=11/18/13}]
```

I want to check particular entry from here using "AppoinmentID" and i want to get that record for a diferent hashmap and all the others to a different one.. how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: imho: storing these values in a hashmap is not a good idea. why don't you create an appointment class. removing an appointment object will be easy in this case. if you want some code for that, let me know and i'll post it as an answer

Comment: yes...please can you give me some codes :)

Comment: @PhilippSander is there any specific reason about "storing these values in a hashmap is not a good idea" ?

Comment: @PankajKumar as you can see, it's harder to handle

Comment: @PhilippSander please give me some code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a class

```
public class Appointment
{
 public int     appointmentId;
 public int     userId;    
 public Date    startTime;
 public Date    endTime;
 public Appointment(int id,int aUserID,Date aStartTime,Date aEndTime)
 {
    this.appointmentId = id;
    this.userId = aUserID;
    this.startTime = aStartTime;
    thiis.endTime =  aEndTime;
 }
}
```

2. Creating Appointment Object and Storing in HashMap

```
String dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm"; //any date format
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);       
 Date startDate = df.parse("January 2, 2010 13:00");
 Date endDate = df.parse("January 2, 2010 20:00");
 Appointment appointment1 = new Appointment(1,23,startDate,endDate);

 ...
 Map<Integer, Appointment> appointments = new HashMap<Integer, Appointment>();
 // add to hashmap making appointment id as key
 appointments.put(appointment1.appointmentId,appointment1);
 ......
 ...
 appointments.put(appointmentN.appointmentId,appointmentN);
```

3. deleting an Appointment Object

```
 appointments.remove(aAppointmentId)
```

4. getting an Appointment  Object

```
Appointment ap = appointments.get(aAppointmentId);
System.out.printLn("id "+ ap.appointmentId);
System.out.printLn("userId "+ ap.userId);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);       
System.out.printLn("starttime "+  df.format(ap.startTime));
System.out.printLn("endtime "+  df.format(ap.endTime));
```

Comment: please don't make members public... it's a matter of encapsulation

Answer (score 1):

storing these values in a hashmap is not a good idea. why don't you create an appointment class. removing an appointment object will be easy in this case.

```
public class Appointment
{
    private int     appointmentId;
    private int     userId;     // or private User user
    private Date    start;
    private Date    end;

    public Appointment(int id)
    {
        this.appointmentId = id;
    }

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        Appointment other = (Appointment) obj;
        if (this.appointmentId != other.appointmentId)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

now if you want to delete a specific item with a certain ID:

```
List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
appointments.remove(new Appointment(theIdYouWantToDelete));
```

or an even better way:

Store them like this

```
Map<Integer, Appointment> appointments = new HashMap<Integer, Appointment>();
appointments.put(appointment.getAppointmentId(), appointment);
```

and remove them like this:

```
appointments.remove(theIdYouWantToDelete);
```

with this approach, you do not need the equals method.

**Why it works:**

When you want to remove an Object from a List or a Map, Java uses the equals method to identify them. As You can see i only check for the `appointmentId`. So if the IDs of 2 object are the same, Java says they are the same object. If you don't override equals, check only checks for `==` (same object in the memory) which mostly isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can have class:

```
public class Apointment{
Stirng EndTime="09:00 AM";
int AppointmentId=79;
...
...
}
```

and have one hashmap with apointmentId as key

```
HashMap<Integer,Apointment> map=new  HashMap<Integer,Apointment>();
Apointment ap=new Apointment(...);

map.put(ap.getAppointmentId(),ap);
..
..
..
```

And if you have apointmentID you can get apointment object by:

```
Apointment ap=map.get(79);
```